# Is there an online resource for latest US presidential campaigns highlights?

Tags: united-states, campaigning

I am interested in the highlights (e.g. platform main ideas, slogans) of the latest (5-6) US presidential campaigns. For example, for the 2016 US presidential campaign the information should look somewhat like the following:

**[Donald Trump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Trump_presidential_campaign,_2016)**

- United States–Mexico border wall and illegal immigration
- temporary Muslim ban proposal
- slogan: Make America {One | Safe | Strong | Work } Again

**[Hilary Clinton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillary_Clinton_presidential_campaign,_2016#Platform)**

- middle class income raise
- women's rights
- campaign finance reform
- Affordable Care Act improvement
- universal preschool
- Wall Street regulation
- support for the right to same-sex marriage
- slogan: stronger together

**Question:** Is there an online resource for latest US presidential campaigns highlights?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a comprehensive answer, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._presidential_campaign_slogans) gathered together a list of United States presidential campaign slogans.

I'm not sure there is going to be an unbiased discussion of the campaign platforms.  For example, your list gets the Donald Trump campaign slogan ("Make America Great Again") incorrect and attributes "middle class income raise" to Hillary Clinton rather than Trump.  Yet that was far more of a Trump emphasis than a Clinton emphasis.  Trump was the one arguing that tax, trade, and regulatory policies were strangling the economy, leaving middle class people unemployed or underemployed.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_positions_of_Donald_Trump), Trump:

> He has proposed sizable income tax cuts and deregulation consistent with conservative (Republican Party) policies, along with significant infrastructure investment and protection for entitlements for the elderly, typically considered liberal (Democratic Party) policies. His anti-globalization policies of trade protectionism and immigration reduction cross party lines.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_positions_of_Hillary_Clinton), Clinton has a similar page, but it lacks the summary.  If I try to summarize it, I get

1. Women, ethnic minorities, and homosexuals need and should get special protections for issues unique to them.
2. The economy is under-regulated.  More could be done to promote fairness, environmental protection, etc.
3. The economy is under-taxed.  Higher taxes on higher income taxpayers could be used for advantageous government spending.

Wikipedia also has pages for positions for

1. [Barack Obama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_positions_of_Barack_Obama).
2. [Mitt Romney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_positions_of_Mitt_Romney).
3. [John McCain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_positions_of_John_McCain).

But previous candidates do not get separate position pages, e.g.

1. [George W. Bush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_W._Bush_presidential_campaign,_2004).
2. [John Kerry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Kerry_presidential_campaign,_2004).

These pages are linked from the various election pages, e.g. [US presidential election, 2004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_election,_2004), as either (positions) or (campaign).